# Memory leak in production Code

Tags: c#, memory-management, concurrency, production-environment

I have an application that runs as a windows service written using C# WCF. In production code we are seeing  a behavior where memory of the application grows slowly. After reviewing the code, we found that there is a dictionary(concurrent) in which items gets added and not removed when job is finished. Items are coming at the rate of around 100 per second. Is there any way we can fix this problem without a code change? or is there anyway that force the application to do garbage collection externally? As I know there is no possibility but just posting it to get to know if anything there.

Item is a object of two properties (both are int).

Comment: Please elaborate: Is your code deleting the dictionary entries but the memory use for it still keeps growing? Why would you need to fix it `without a code change`? You can force a garbage collection from within the code at any time, obviously, though it's rarely a good idea.

Comment: I don't think forcing garbage collection is going to help, you still hold reference to them in your dictionary, garbage collection doesn't selectively delete items from your dictionary. Only time you will get memory freed is if Dictionary as a whole gets garbage collection, which I dont think is your case. So you need code change.

Comment: If you not need a dictionary, maybe you could use a concurrent queue. As soon an item from a queue is dequeued it is free and can be collected by the garbage collector.. If a Dictionary is required, than I would do a 'RemoveKey' to release the reference..

Comment: problem is item added to the dictionary is never be removed.  What happens after it reaches the max it can use?

Comment: It will throw an 'OutOfMemoryException'.

Comment: Will it kill the application in any point in time?

Comment: What is the life time of the Dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

If you move your app to be run by IIS as an app pool then you can configure app pool ["recycle"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(v=ws.10).aspx). One of the options is [recycle on Virtual Memory usage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732519(v=ws.10).aspx), which how ASP deals with memory leaks.

You can also roll your own recycle, monitor your service memory usage and restart it when it reaches a threshold.

Of course, app recycle *does* mean a process restart and your WCF service may react badly to this, your API calls may experience reduced SLAs, and worse you may expose unwanted behavior in your WCF service (bugs). But pretty much is the only way to 'control' a leak in production w/o a redeploy.

Ideally, fix the leak and re-deploy.